# How to make child divs width extend to full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are multiple rows of containers like this on my page so when its displayed on a small screen the elements move inline. 
I want the orange bar to sit behind and slightly below the header and fill the width of the page. Therefore I've used relative positioning and negative z-index on the orange bar to push it underneath the title.

My question is how can I make the backbars width equal to the width of the screen while keeping it inside the div holding the title?

```css
.backbar_orange {
    background-color: rgb(250, 105, 0);
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     
 <div class="backbar_orange"></div>
     
    <h2>Sticker</h2>  
 <p>Content here</p>
     
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="img/stckr.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydh8s2mk/)

I hope this makes sense, I tried to post an image explaining my design.

I've seen people mention using jQuery but surely theres a way to do it in css? I've no experience with jQuery.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the image with your design? Are you using bootstrap? From your explanation I don't quite understand what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Your orange bar (to me) is the width of the screen, and you placed it inside the div with the title... so I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps be a bit more descriptive (or include an image) of what your desire end result is.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using bootstrap.

Comment: This is what I want, http://postimg.org/image/6fxv623fp/

Comment: This is what I've got http://postimg.org/image/nkzc9mtc9/

Comment: It looks like, perhaps, you're misusing bootstrap. The Bootstrap classes you are using specifically control the width of the content, so perhaps you don't actually want the `<div>` included with the headings. I only recently started using Bootstrap, however, so perhaps I'm not the best person to comment.

Comment: For example: removing the div from the nested group you have: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydh8s2mk/1/)

Comment: I'm attempting to keep responsiveness, so I want the orange div to be anchored to the header so the relative positioning remains intact. The same code will be repeated multiple times down the page. When viewed on mobile, if the div bars are not anchored they wont show up in the right place. I may well be misusing bootstrap :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at, the width is the size of my monitor for me, I assume you're trying to add the backbar under the header in which case you could just use a padding in css.

However based on your images it looks like you want the width to line up in a column next to an image of sorts.

in which case you can us ethe bootstrap grid abilities found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

to create two columns and set their own width and height etc, for the divs inside each column.